# Problem with iterating over a lots of images in OpenCv with mac os

Tags: c++, macos, file-io, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to iterator over some directories containing approximately 3000 images. I load the image. If the image is loaded I release it. 
That is the smallest program that I can write to reproduce the error.

After loading and releasing 124 images the program stops loading images. I think this a **memory** issue but I don't understand what exactly causes the program to stop loading images.

I'm using **OpenCV** on my **Mac**. I don't know how exactly I can figure out which version I'm using.

Here is the Code from my project.

```
bool FaceDetectionStrategy::detectFace(std::string imagePath) {

   IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(imagePath.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   if (img) {
      std::cout << "Image loaded " << imagePath << std::endl;
      cvReleaseImage(&img);
   } else {
      std::cout << "Image not loaded " << imagePath << std::endl;
   }
return true;
```

}

This method is called for every image in the directorys I'm iterating through. After 124 images the if(img) part evaluates to false and the else branch is executed. If I try to load images from other parts of the program later on they also won't load.

**Edit** it is not a memory issue. Mac Os standard max open files is 256 after changing it to 512 I can open 251 images. so it seems that OpenCV doesn't closes the image files after loading them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching the bugtracker from OpenCv showed this answer to the problem: [cvLoadImage with Mac ImageIO leaves file handles open](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2540871&group_id=22870&atid=376677).

It seems that this is a bug in the OpenCV mac implementation and the only way to solve it is to install a newer version of OpenCV.

**EDIT** installing the last version of OpenCV from the repository trunk solves the problem. Sometimes it helps checking the BugTracker of the frameworks you are using...

Comment: Heh, that's too bad :( Good to know you weren't crazy though, huh?

Answer (score 2):

Behavior concerning memory rarely has to do with a consistent number, in my experience. The only way it could be that consistent is if there is some sort of internal limit in `cvLoadImage` that happens to be the not-very-common number 124. But your logic seems fine to me, that your images should be released.

More likely, since I assume your directories aren't changing between tests, that 125th image is bad.

Have you verified that the image you are trying to load actually exists? If it does (which it probably does), check that the image file format is [supported by OpenCV](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00052000000000000000). If that is also true, make sure the file is not corrupted by opening it with another editor.

You can have OpenCV [help you out with errors](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/error_handling_and_system_functions.html). Use [`cvGetErrStatus()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/error_handling_and_system_functions.html#cvGetErrStatus) to check if there was an error, then use [`cvErrorStr()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/error_handling_and_system_functions.html#cvErrorStr) to get a textual description of it. You can do something like this:

```
// I would recommend putting this in a file, like CVUtility.h

#include <exception>

void check_CV_Error(void)
{
    int errorCode = cvGetErrStatus();
    if (errorCode) // I'm assuming 0 means no reportable error
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(cvErrorStr(errorCode));
        // std::cerr << cvErrorStr(errorCode);
        // ^ if you would rather not use exceptions
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
bool FaceDetectionStrategy::detectFace(std::string imagePath) {

   IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(imagePath.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   if (img) {
      std::cout << "Image loaded " << imagePath << std::endl;
      cvReleaseImage(&img);
   } else {
      std::cout << "Image not loaded " << imagePath << std::endl;
      check_CV_Error(); // find reason for error
   }
return true;
```

And that will throw an exception for you to catch and log, and possibly react on. (Or print the error to console if you use the `std::cerr` version)

Comment: The error code is zero. So either OpenCV doesn't causes the error or doesn't set an error code.

I loaded all the images with OpenCV before but not that much inside one run so the images should be compatible to OpenCV.

Comment: Try deleting or moving one of the first 100 and see if the problem moves itself to a new bitmap, to be sure. That will eliminate "it's a specific picture" ideas.

Comment: Beginning with another directory first produced the same error. The images are not all the same size something between 20 and 60 K but the number of images I can open stays the same. Maybe I need to do something else to force OpenCV releasing the file handle? That would be a reason for the numbers of images I can load staying the same.